# Any suggestions for optimizing this code?

Tags: c#, optimization

I have written a code from the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967937/32bit-rgb-bmp-to-24bit-rgb-bmp-in-c-problem)

My sample code is as follows

```
void Process(int i)
{
    input = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"filepath.bmp");

    Bitmap temp = new Bitmap(input.Width, input.Height, 
                             PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(temp);
    g.Clear(Color.Red);
    g.DrawImage(input, Point.Empty);

    temp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    //I need this stream thats further processing
}

void timer_Ex()
{
    int i = 11;
    for (; ; )
    {
      if (i == 335) break;
      else
      {
         st.Start();
         Process(i);
         st.Stop();    
         Console.WriteLine(st.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
            //This time is more than the time in which thread sleeps
         st.Reset();                       
         Thread.Sleep(70);                     
         i++;
       }
   }
}
```

So I am trying to convert image from rgb32 to rgb24. But it takes more time on processing than the time in which thread sleeps. Its just a sample code. So just help me with this question
"How can i optimize process(int i) to execute in 20 ms or less than 100 ms?"

Comment: @The Scrum Meister :) i dont know what to say :P

Comment: who is calling timer_Ex? and how often?

Comment: If the problem really is that the processing takes more time then the sleep time, you should stop the timer in the Process method and re-start it when you're done. There is no guarantee that things will be faster the 70ms because the time is dependent on the file being processed and what else is going on on your machine. So stop the timer in the beginning of your Process method and re-start it at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Things to dramatically improve your code:-

1. your "input" image is always the same image. But you load it every time Process() is called. Make it a member, and load it once only.
2. Your "temp" bitmap is allocated every time you call Process(), again it does not need to be. Make it a member, and allocate it once.
3. You don't dispose of any of your Graphics objects. Bitmaps should be disposed when you are done with them, as should Graphics.

Not really a performance thing, but your for loop is very very odd, and unreadable. Why do you try to reinvent language constructs that are built in? what is wrong with

```
for (int i=11; i != 335 ; i++)
{

     st.Start();
     Process(i);
     st.Stop();    
     Console.WriteLine(st.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
        //This time is more than the time in which thread sleeps
     st.Reset();                       
     Thread.Sleep(70);   }
```

Comment: Thanks alot for advices. Well about the loop, thats really stupid of me to have it like that. Thanks for this tip too:)

Answer (score 1):

1. *Graphics* goes against COM+. It's slow. Use the Media-namespace that came with WPF.

For the rest of it; it depends. Input size, machine configuration (dx version, graphics card), your skills with C and p/invoke.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are going to make the same size of image the following line can be removed

g.Clear(Color.Red);

It may not make much difference but it can reduce your time

Answer (score 1):

You might want to run it in parallel - whilst each image will still take the same amount of time, you'll be able to process more at once (assuming you have more than 1 core in your CPU)